# Running a script pre-build in react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have some resource files that I need to copy from `/app/resources` to both `/android/app/src/main/ress/raw` and `/ios/<project>/resources` when I build.  I assume there's a way to do this, but I'm not familiar with how [`react-native`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)/Gradle/XCode builds.

For gradle, I tried adding to `/android/app/build.gradle`

```
task copySounds(type: Copy) {
    from '../../app/resources/sounds/*'
    into 'src/main/res/raw/'
}
```

and to `/android/.idea/workspace.xml`

```
<project version="4">
  // ...
  <component name="GradleLocalSettings">
    // ...
    <option name="availableTasks">
      <map>
        <entry>
          // ...
          <value>
            <list>
              // ...
              <ExternalTaskPojo>
                <option name="linkedExternalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
                <option name="name" value="copySounds" />
              </ExternalTaskPojo>
              // ...
            </list>
          </value>
        </entry>
        // ...
      </map>
    </option>
    // ...
  </component>
</project>
```

but it didn't seem to do anything.  My guess is I need to add a third reference somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Answer (score 3):

This could be done in the scripts section of package.json at the root of your project.

For instance, below I am running ./scripts/script-to-run-before-RN-build.sh before React Native packager is being called to perform the build.

```
"scripts": {
      "start": "npm run pre-packager && node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
      "pre-packager": "./scripts/script-to-run-before-RN-build.sh"
}
```

Comment: How does this work in detail? I have tried to call react-native bundle/run-android in both cases pre-packager won't be called.

Comment: The pre-packager will only run when calling `yarn start` or `yarn run pre-packager` the command `yarn start` calls `pre-packager`